# How to print very long images (e.g. 10" x 64") on a single sheet of paper

Tags: print-production, digital-printing

I've got a very long image (10" x 64") that I would like to print on regular paper.  Most of the printing services I've seen print either posters (e.g. 24x36) or vinyl banners (e.g. for hanging outside a store).  Is there a printer that can just print something arbitrarily long (i.e. from a spool)?  Are there services that can do that?  I thought plotters did that, but when I researched plotters a it more, it sounds like they are for vector images (as opposed to photograph-style images).

And just to be clear - I do not want something like a big heavy-duty plastic banner that a company might put up at a trade show or outside their store.  I just want something printed on regular paper from a spool.

Comment: No clue if this helps for India...... but try your local FedEx Kinkos if there is one. Or some similar venue. They typically have a large scale Epson printer for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ahh - didn't realize I hadn't updated my profile.  Not in India anymore - back in Jersey.  But looking at FexEx's website, they don't seem to offer that.  But I'll call and see... thanks

Comment: I just looked.. the FedEx site has things under "Banners" that would most likely work. Appears to be up to 10 feet, and you may have to trim the width on your own.

Comment: You probably want a company that has a large format inkjet printer. Apart from digital print companies, architect's or builder's offices often have them for printing architectural drawings - and yes these are generally spool fed, so you can have a banner almost any length you desire.  You may have to cut it to size yourself however, since the rolls are usually much wider than 10".

Comment: Scott - all the FedEx banner stuff seems to be much heavier-duty than I want - looks like printing on thick plastic or something like that, to stand up to being hung by corners.  I'm looking for someone who can just print on a spool of regular paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact a shop that prints wide format, has an Epson Surecolor printer with photo paper, and has the ability to flatbed cut paper.
I don't know how you could find one in Jersey, but there's one in Wisconsin.
[Digital Edge](http://digitaledgecc.com)

Answer (score 0):

Most big format inkjets print on spools. So most services who print posters with inkjets can print on as long paper their spooholder can hold. But a shop that specializes in bulk might have a sheet based system. It depends, ask them. It makes sense to advertize what people buy. The end result is cut to specification almost always anyway.

Plotters are systems that draw with pens. Mainly used by architectural companies, engineers and fashion designers. If you need a technical drawing for archivial with real crisp lines plotters are the way to go, but more expensive since they are slower than inkjets for example. Think of them like vinyl cutters but with pens.  Yes they also frequently have the same formfactor as a inkjet as the thechnical function of the frame is nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution to print large image is to print on multiple pages.

1. Convert your image into a PDF file using [Adobe Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/) (Free)
2. Create PDF > PDF from File (Select your image)
3. File > Print > Poster (This will split the image into multiple pages)
4. Adjust the Tile Scale to fit the image and Print.

See this reference about how it is done.
https://allthingsencaustic.com/print-image-multiple-pages/